# How to send data back from a process file? (e.g errors)

Tags: php, forms, authentication, error-handling

I'm working on a login system, and I was wondering how to send errors back to the form?
I will personally use AJAX in my project so it won't really a problem but I'm curious to know how it's possible with pure php.

This is the form... On `login.php` or some other page:

```
<form method="post" action="proccessLogin.php">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

`processLogin.php`:

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(password is incorrect){
        // send error or add to an error array and then send it.
    }

    etc...
?>
```

This is just a piece of code I just wrote so it's obviously not complete.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use session to set the errors.. refer below modified code..

```
login.php

<?php
session_start();
?>
<form method="post" action="proccessLogin.php">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <?php if($_SESSION['u_name_error']) { echo $_SESSION['u_name_error']; unset($_SESSION['u_name_error']); }
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <?php if($_SESSION['pass_error']) { echo $_SESSION['pass_error']; unset($_SESSION['pass_error']); }
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>

==============
proccessLogin.php
<?php
session_start();

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(password is incorrect){
        // send error or add to an error array and then send it.
    }else{

        //set errors in session..
        $_SESSION['pass_error']= 'error message';
        $_SESSION['u_name_error']= 'error message';
        header("Location: login.php");
        die;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could go the reload_page and $_GET error message route.

```
// Set your error messages here
$error_messages = "?password_error=true"
header("Location: http://localhost/url_to_form.php" + $error_messages);
exit();
```

Once you're in your form file do a check for known error variables

```
$error_message_list = array( "password_error" => "Incorrect password" );
foreach ($_GET as $error_name => $error_value) {
    if ( in_array( $error_name, $error_message_list ) ) {
        $error_to_display[$error_name] = $error_message_list[$error_name];
    } else {
        $error_to_display[$error_name] = "";
    }
}
```

After this check-up, just place $error_to_display[ "password_error" ] somewhere in your HTML, like so`echo '<label for="password">Password: ' . $error_to_display[ "password_error" ] . '</label>';`